# How to convert xls{,x} to csv file so that formulas show as text using Python?

Tags: python, csv, excel-formula

I want to preserve the excel file formulas as text in csv.

For example,

a.xlsx

```
A | B
-----
1 | 6
2 | 
3 |
```

where column `B` is `=SUM(A:A)`

what I want the converted csv to look like is:

```
A,B
1,=SUM(A:A)
2
3
```

currently, I am reading excel as a `df` using `pandas` and using `to_csv` to generate the csv which produces

```
A,B
1,6
2
3
```

My python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

def main():
    with open("dir_list.txt") as myfile:
        fileformat = 'csv'
        lines = myfile.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            name=line
            inputfile=str(line) + ".xlsx"
            
            #if directory exists, remove it before creating new  
            if os.path.exists(name) and os.path.isdir(name):
                shutil.rmtree(name)

            try:
                os.makedirs(name)
            except:
                pass
            df1 = pd.read_excel(inputfile, sheet_name=None, engine='openpyxl')
            print('============================================================')
            print(f'Processing {inputfile}')
            print('============================================================')
            for x,_ in df1.items():
                print(x + '.' + fileformat, 'Done!')
                df2 = pd.read_excel(inputfile, sheet_name=x, engine='openpyxl')
                filename = os.path.join(name, x + '.' + fileformat)
                if fileformat == 'csv':
                    df2.to_csv(filename, index=False)
                else:
                    df2.to_excel(filename, index=False)
            print(f'\nCreated CSVs inside {name}')
            print('============================================================')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

file `dir_list.txt` contains just the excel file name without the extension. So for example, an excel file of name abc.xlsx, should make dir_list.txt look like

```
abc
```